# jtds ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on Jre 1.8.66

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, jtds

We have come across a weird ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in JTDS when running on jre-1.8_66 and have not been able to find any other mention of this issue on the web.

I have been able to replicate this error using both the jtds 1.2.5 and 1.2.8 when running the 32 bit version of jre-1.8_66 when using the server jvmdll. When using the 64-bit JRE or the 32-bit client jvm.dll I am unable to replicate the error.

I am also unable to replicate the error at all when running in Eclipse or when attempting to remote debug from Eclipse so I can't narrow down the specific cause of the issue.

The full stack trace is below.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsData.readData(TdsData.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsRowToken(TdsCore.java:3081)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2346)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:777)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.next(JtdsResultSet.java:596)
    at test.jtdstest.JtdsText.main(JtdsText.java:51)
```

I've the jtds code at the point where the exception occurs and I can't specifically see anything wrong with it but I could easily be mistaken.

The test program I wrote to replicate the error is below.

```
package test.jtdstest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JtdsText
{

   private static PrintWriter pw;

   static
   {
      try
      {
         pw = new PrintWriter(new File("c:\\temp\\jtds_trace.txt"));
         DriverManager.setLogWriter(pw);
         Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
      }
      catch (Exception localException)
      {
      }
   }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws Exception
  {
     Connection conn = null;
     PreparedStatement stmt = null;
     ResultSet res = null;
     try
     {
         String sql = 
            "SELECT "
            + "text1, "
            + "int1, "
            + "int2, "
            + "text2 "
            + "FROM "
            + "text_test";

        conn =      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/test;user=user1;password=aa");
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        res = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (res.next())
        {
            int int1 = res.getInt(2);
            System.out.println("int1 = " + Integer.toString(int1));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         System.out.println("Error processing result set:");
         ex.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println();
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
          if(res != null)
          {
             res.close();
          }

          if(stmt != null)
          {
             stmt.close();
          }

          if(conn != null)
          {
             conn.close();
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          System.out.println("Error cleaning up Statement:");
          ex.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can provide the data I used to replicate the error as well if required.

I strongly suspect this to be a bug in the JRE since that's the only variable that changes to be able to replicate the error.

Has anybody come across this before? Other than changing the JVM is there any other way to overcome the error? Should I rather be reporting this bug against the JVM?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a bug in the JIT compiler. Turning off the JIT compiler using the -Xint option resolves the issue. We are in the process of logging this with Oracle to address.

Comment: You have to have a link to the Oracle bug id for this?